# Camel read body request and perform choice

Tags: apache-camel

I'm very new to camel and I need to do a "simple" things, but it's becoming a nightmare..

My flow is:

- Create and endpoint that can be called as `POST` with a JSON body with a single parameter `myVar`
- If the parameter is `true`, populate a value in a map
- If is false (or not present) populate another value:

Reading the documentation I found [this](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html) article, that describe the usage of `when()` so, I wrote the following code:

```
final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
rest()
    .post("/my-endpoint")
    .choice()
    .when().simple("${body.myVar} == true")
        .process(e -> parameters.put("key", "the value is true")
    .otherwise()
        .process(e -> parameters.put("key", "the value is false")
    .to("direct:another-processor");
```

The `another-processor` have to use the values on `parameters`

When I run this code and I perform a POST to my-endpoint i get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: myVar not found on bean: {
    "myVar": "false"
} of type: java.lang.String on the exchange
```

What I'm doing wrong? OPr maybe, there is a better way to accomplish this result ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Camel Simple language's [OGNL expression support](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html#_ognl_expression_support).

> ...Camel’s OGNL support is for invoking methods only. You cannot
> access fields.  ...**Suppose the Message IN body contains a POJO which
> has a `getAddress()` method.**
>
> Then you can use Camel OGNL notation to access the address object:
> `simple("${body.address}")`
>
> Camel understands the shorthand names for getters, but you can invoke any method or use  the real name such as:
> `simple("${body.getAddress.getStreet}")`

For `${body.myVar}`, camel is trying to call method (`getMyVar` or `myVar`) of `java.lang.String` (the type of your in body from your error statement). As `String` class does not contain both methods, your code results in `MethodNotFoundException`.

To prevent this, you have to convert your in body from `java.lang.String` to POJO contains method (`getMyVar` or `myVar`) before you use OGNL. You can use [unmarshal](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/json.html) to achieve this.